# How to remove read-only attribute of a folder by powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have tried many code but still I am not able to remove read-only property of that particular folder.

Below is the code which removes read-only property of the files present under that folder but does not remove read-only attribute of that Folder :

```
$Path = "C:\Suraj\powershell scripts\review script" 
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse
ForEach ($File in $Files) {
    Write-Host file:$File IsReadOnly: $File.IsReadOnly 
    if ($File.Attributes -ne "Directory" -and $File.Attributes -ne "Directory, Archive") {
        try {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $Path"\"$File -name IsReadOnly -value $false 
        }
        catch { 
            Write-Host "Error at file " $Path "\" $File 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you'd need to?  The read only attribute on a folder doesn't do much.  It doesn't affect items in the folder, nor does it prevent you from renaming or deleting the folder.  As far as I know, it's only used to indicate folders that are system-created.  [See the Cause section here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/326549/you-cannot-view-or-change-the-read-only-or-the-system-attributes-of-fo).  You can, however, use the `attrib` method described there to make the change.

Comment: One liner for ps v3+ to remove read-only attribute: `Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -File | foreach { $_.IsReadOnly=$false }`

Comment: I agree with Bacon Bits - what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Actually i am using this script through build definition to push the nuget package but its giving me error and the reason i got to know is because the particular folder which has dll's in it is in read-only mode so i want to remove the read-only attribute of it, but i am unable to do that i tried multiple code but still it remains in read-only mode.

Comment: So i took out the script and tried to remove the read-only attribute but i found out that it remove read-only attribute from the files present inside the folder but the folder itself remains in Read-Only mode.

Comment: No James C, even that doesn't work it only removes read-only attribute of files present inside the folder but the folder still remains in read-only mode.

Comment: I'll be the third to add the question, why do you need to remove the attribute from the folder? What problem is the folder being read-only causing that you need to set that? Normally it's not a problem at the folder level.

Comment: Actually i was not able to copy the file into that folder and also the file which were already present in that folder i was not able to push them as a package to a proget server, but anyways i am able to do it now by doing some changes in the scripts.

Answer (score 6):

Whether a folder has the `ReadOnly` attribute set or not, can be verified with:

```
$folder = Get-Item -Path path/to/folder
$folder.Attributes
```

Default output will be:

> `Directory`

To add the `ReadOnly` attribute, just execute:

```
$folder.Attributes = $folder.Attributes -bor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly
```

If you display the attributes again, it should look like this:

> `ReadOnly, Directory`

To remove the `ReadOnly` attribute, just execute:

```
$folder.Attributes = $folder.Attributes -band -bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly
```

The attributes look like that again:

> `Directory`

As you can see, it is indeed possible to add and remove the `ReadOnly` attribute, but as others already mentioned in the comments, it won't have much of an effect.

---

The `ReadOnly` attribute can also be added and/or removed in a more readable way:

```
$folder.Attributes += 'ReadOnly'
$folder.Attributes -= 'ReadOnly'
```

But be aware, that this does not work reliably, if you add the attribute when it already exists or if you remove it when it does not exist. This is because the attributes are stored in a bit field. Subtracting an unset bit will flip many other bits instead of just this one bit.

Comment: `$folder.Attributes -= 'ReadOnly'` made the folder `Hidden`

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers never worked for me. The only command which actually removes the attribute is this one:

```
attrib -s -h -r "c:\path_to_folder\*.*" /s /d
```

> Description:
>
> - -s Remove system attribute
> - -h Remove hidden attribute
> - -r Remove read-only attribute
> - /s Set/remove attributes in current folder and including subfolders
> - /d Set/remove attributes of folders too

Source: https://superuser.com/a/1199334/1078173

NB: the property of the top folder will still be defined as `Read-only (Only applies to files in folder)` but the files will be correctly set as non read-only files
[image]

You can check that files are correctly defined with the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\path_to_folder" -File -Recurse | foreach {$_.Attributes}
```