# How manage dirs in var value off Powershell from Ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible, powershell-5.0

Ansible: 2.9 PowerShell: 5 OS: w2k16 Server

Hi all!

I have a dir created with "Read-only (Only applies to files in folder)" in windows target host. I need to remove this attribut.

I write this code in Powershell :

```
- name: "Change rules dir for all"
  win_shell: |
    $mypath= c:\tmp
    $myacl= Get-ACL "$mypath"
    $myaclentry= "everyone","FullControl","Allow"
    $ruleexecutor= New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($myaclentry)
    $myacl.SetAccesRule($ruleexecutor)
    $myACL | Set-Acl $mypath
    Get-ACL "$mypath" | fl
```

But I have this result:

Error:

```
"stderr": "c:\\tmp : The term 'c:\\tmp' is not recognized as the name of a
 cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:73
+ ... ::InputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false; $mypath=c:\\tmp
+                                                                    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\\tmp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Get-Acl : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. 
The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not 
null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:2 char:17
+ $myacl= Get-ACL \"$mypath\"
+ 
...
```

Questions:

- Why my code don't run?
- Why "\" is not recognized?
- How to change a simple attribut in dir with Powershell?

Thank's Again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have many reponses:

- Why my code don't run?
  By many reasons:

  - The double "\" syntax.
  - Because "SetAccesRule" is not found in my system I need to modify a GPO from AD Server.
  - The explicit syntax in the win_shell ansible module when I get value vars.
  - The differences between ' or " in the paths (yes next time I will create a question of this subject) .
- Why "\" is not recognized?

  - I need to add a other "\" in "c:\tmp" value var.
    Read a: [Using Ansible and Windows](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/windows_usage.html)
- How to change a simple attribut in dir with Powershell?

  - I don't know, I ignored the "ReadOnly" because I can write in the dir.
    More info here: [how-to-remove-read-only-attribute-of-a-folder-by-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159963/how-to-remove-read-only-attribute-of-a-folder-by-powershell)
    but when i execute this code `$folder.Attributes -= 'ReadOnly'` my file change to hidden file. Thats is other reason I ignored this "ReadOnly".

To end, my solution has in the Powershell command:

```
task: Create dir
win_shell: |
  New-Item -Path c:\temp -ItemType directory # Of corse here without double '\\'
```